# Set variable within another context

Tags: javascript, image, syntax, onload, strict

I have the following function

```
"use strict";
function Player
{
    this.width;
    this.height;
    this.framesA = 5;

    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.onload = function ()
    {
        width = this.width;
        height = this.height / framesA;
    }
    this.image.src = "Images/angel.png";
}
```

How can I make this code to work?
I want the width and height in the Player function be inalized with the width and the height of the image when the onload function is called.

I need this to work with strict mode (A must).

If this should be accomplished another way feel free to teach.

**EDIT:** I updated the code to reflect a more realistic situation(I didn't know this will be so complicated)

**EDIT 2:** Another update to the code. I didn't notice that I wrote var insted of this. Sorry.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use `this.image.width` and `this.image.height`...

Comment: Your example should work, I think, what is the problem?

Comment: @Šime Vidas I need to save the value so a solution will be apriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I gathered from your comments was that you want to be able to access the width and height from outside the `Player` function and the problem is that you don't know when the width and height are available.

If that is correct, it gets a bit more complicated. Since you don't know when the image will be loaded and can't have the width and height before it's loaded (unless you specify them in the `img` tag server-side), you need to use a function that takes a callback to access the player's width and height.

Basically, if the width and height are not known yet, the function just puts the callback in a queue. When the width and height are determined, all of the functions in the queue get called with the width and height being passed to them as arguments. If the dimensions are already know when the function is called, it should just immediately call the callback function with the correct arguments.

Here's how I'd do this:

```
function Player() {
    'use strict';

    // Store this in a variable so the onload handler can see it.
    var that = this;
    var callbacks = [];

    this.frames = 5;

    this.getDimensions = function (callback) {
        // We don't have the dimensions yet, so put the callback in the queue.
        callbacks.push(callback);
    };

    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.onload = function () {
        var width = this.width;
        var height = this.height / that.frames;

        // Call each of the registered callbacks.
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i += 1) {
            callbacks[i](width, height);
        }
        // Don't keep unnecessary references to the functions.
        callbacks = null;

        // We now know the dimensions, so we can replace the getDimensions
        // function with one that just calls the callback.
        that.getDimensions = function (callback) {
            callback(width, height);
        };
    };
    this.image.src = "Images/angel.png";
}
```

And here's how you'd access the dimensions:

```
var p = new Player();
p.getDimensions(function (width, height) {
    console.log("Player's width is " + width + " and height is " + height);
});
```

Comment: Just 1 question: var that = this is copied(by value) or is memory adress copied(by refrence)?

Comment: @RandallFlagg, `that` and `this` point to the same object, it's not copied.

Answer (score 2):

Just set your variables and do your manipulations from within the `onload` event and they will stay in scope.

```
"use strict";
function Player
{
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = "Images/angel.png";
    this.image.onload = function ()
    {
        var width = this.width;
        var height = this.height;
        // Do your manipulations within the `onload` event.
    } 
}
```

Comment: yikes, definitely not what the OP is asking for, there will be multiple players, you can't share the width

Comment: Your second example wouldn't work because the image won't be loaded (unless it's cached) when you call `width = this.image.width`. For this approach to work, you have to wait for the onload event.

Comment: @Juan, you are correct! I initially mistook `Player` for a standard method. I fixed the lone solution to use the `onload` event and perform manipulations from within.

Comment: JavaScript allows you to declare variables in an outer function and use them in an inner one: `(function () { var a; (function () { a = 3; }()); window.alert(a); }())` (alerts `3`). So scoping isn't the problem.

Comment: This is a scoping issue because when the onload is called the scope moves to the image and it is not inside the Player

Comment: @Randall, what are you doing with the width and height? Can you just perform your manipulations inside the `onload` event?

Comment: Randal, I don't think it's  a scoping the problem, in your onload handler, `this` should be the image, so `this.width` should give you what you need.

Comment: @JustinSatyr: Now, with your example, if the image is already cached, you may miss the onload event. You should set the `onload` before you set `src`.

Comment: I can't do manipulation in the onload since I need information from Player. I updated the code so you could see. About the scping issue you are correct that this.width will work from the image but my problem was that I need to assign it to width of Player

Answer (score 0):

Here's what  [Šime Vidas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425275/ime-vidas) really means

```
"use strict";
function Player {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = "Images/angel.png";
}

Player.prototype.getWidth = function() {
    return this.image.width;
}
```

or if you like closure based objects

```
function Player {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = "Images/angel.png";
    this.getWidth = function() {
      return this.image.width;
    }
}
```

Comment: No you don't... It just won't be available until it's loaded. Just like in your case, `width` won't be defined until the image has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This variant passes through JSLint without any problem and also works well. So what's the problem?

```
function Player() {
    "use strict";
    var width, height;
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.onload = function () {
        width = this.width;
        height = this.height;
    };
    this.image.src = "Images/angel.png";
}
```

Note that you should place "use strict"; inside function rather then outside.

Comment: A. I know this goes through JSLint B. All my code is strict so there is no need to put it in the function because it is used in the entire file C. The problem is that if you test it in a browser that supports strict mode (I test on Chromium) you will see that width and height are undifined.

Comment: I am sorry but I had misled you. width and height are the properties of Player and are not defined as var. I updated my code.